# How to use .contains() in PySpark to filter by single or multiple substrings?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is a simple question (I think) but I'm not sure the best way to answer it.

I need to filter based on presence of "substrings" in a column containing strings in a Spark Dataframe.

Currently I am doing the following (filtering using `.contains`):

```
data = [[1, "ABC"], [2, "DEF"], [3, "DEF"], [4, "JFKLMN"], [5, "JFKOPQ"], [6, "MNO"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item", "String"])
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

but I want generalize this so I can filter to one or more strings like below:

```
filtered_sdf = sdf.filter(
    spark_fns.col("String").contains("JFK") | spark_fns.col("String").contains("ABC")
)
```

or

```
filtered_sdf = sdf.filter(
    spark_fns.col("String").contains("ABC")
)
```

where ***ideally***, the `.contains()` portion is a pre-set parameter that contains 1+ substrings.

Does anyone know what the best way to do this would be? Or an alternative method?

I've tried using `.isin(substring_list)` but it doesn't work because we are searching for presence of substrings.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a regex pattern that fits all your desired patterns:

```
list_desired_patterns = ["ABC", "JFK"]
regex_pattern = "|".join(list_desired_patterns)
```

Then apply the rlike Column method:

```
filtered_sdf = sdf.filter(
    spark_fns.col("String").rlike(regex_pattern)
)
```

This will filter *any* match within the list of desired patterns.

Comment: This solution also worked for me when I needed to check if a list of strings were present in just a substring of the column (i.e. if a list of letters were present in the last two characters of the column). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using regex matching solves the problem!

```
filtered_sdf = sdf.filter(
    spark_fns.col("String").contains("JFK") | spark_fns.col("String").rlike("ABC")
)
```