# PySpark - filter data frame based on field containing any value from a list

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a list of values called `codes`, and I want to exclude any record from a Spark dataframe whose `codelist` field includes any of the values in the `codes` list.

```
codes = ['O30', 'O81', 'Z38']


from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

dfrows = [
    ("Jane", "Doe", "I13; Z22; F11"),
    ("Janet", "Doser", "O81; F22; I11"),
    ("Jean", "Dew", "D11; O30; Z00; D10"),
    ("Janey", "Doedoe", "D11; Z38; Z00; O81"),
    ("Jena", "Dote", "I13"),
    ("Jenae", "Dee", "O30")
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("fakefirstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("fakelastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("codelist", StringType(), True)
  ])
 
scdf = sc.createDataFrame(data=dfrows ,schema=schema)

scdf.show()
# +-------------+------------+------------------+
# |fakefirstname|fakelastname|          codelist|
# +-------------+------------+------------------+
# |         Jane|         Doe|     I13; Z22; F11|
# |        Janet|       Doser|     O81; F22; I11|
# |         Jean|         Dew|D11; O30; Z00; D10|
# |        Janey|      Doedoe|D11; Z38; Z00; O81|
# |         Jena|        Dote|               I13|
# |        Jenae|         Dee|               O30|
# +-------------+------------+------------------+
```

After removing all records where the `codelist` field contains any value from the `code` list, then I should end up with the final dataframe:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+
|fakefirstname|fakelastname|     codelist|
+-------------+------------+-------------+
|         Jane|         Doe|I13; Z22; F11|
|         Jena|        Dote|          I13|
+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept searching after posting, and found a similar question with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73489134/4716625) that allows me to do what I'm looking for:

```
regex_pattern = "|".join(codes)

scdf.filter(~F.col('codelist').rlike(regex_pattern)).show()
# +-------------+------------+-------------+
# |fakefirstname|fakelastname|     codelist|
# +-------------+------------+-------------+
# |         Jane|         Doe|I13; Z22; F11|
# |         Jena|        Dote|          I13|
# +-------------+------------+-------------+
```